# Only last object in array being inserted into Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to insert data from an array into Core Data, but only the last object from the array is going into the database.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    [self addToCoreData];
}


-(void)addToCoreData {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSError *error;
NSManagedObject *object;
object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

for (int x = 1; x < [_myArray count]; x++) {
    [object setValue:_myArray[x] forKey:@"name"];
}
[context save:&error];

[self fetchData]; //Puts data into UITableview
}
```

I checked the SQLite file and only "3" had been inserted.

Comment: You only have one NSEntityDescription.  Hence only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving creating of the managed object into the loop:

```
-(void)addToCoreData {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

     NSError *error;
     NSManagedObject *object;


    for (int x = 1; x < [_myArray count]; x++) {
        object = [NSEntityDescription    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [object setValue:_myArray[x] forKey:@"name"];
    }
    [context save:&error];

    [self fetchData]; //Puts data into UITableview
}
```

Comment: Got a SIGABRT: '[NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Never mind, the SIGABRT was partially unrelated, that's fixed the array problem, cheers